# How memory leak can happen in this code

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, shared-ptr

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570638/Ten-Cplusplus-Features-Every-Cplusplus-Developer) I read an example which can leak memory

```
void foo(std::shared_ptr<int> p, int init)
{
  *p = init;
}
foo(std::shared_ptr<int>(new int(42)), seed()); // assume seed() returns an int
```

The article says if `seed()` throws, then there will be a memory leak. I am not understanding how?

If the `shared_ptr` is created first, and then `seed()` throws an exception, during stack unwinding, the temporary `shared-ptr` will be destroyed, deallocating the memory. If `seed()` throws error beforehand, then there will be no allocation at the first place.

What I am missing?

Comment: This will explain why => http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_102/

Comment: short answer: the `new int(42)` could execute before `seed()` executes, and before its result is bound to the function parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the order of execution can be

```
auto temp = new int(42);
auto temp2 = seed(); // if throw exception, temp is leaked
auto temp3 = std::shared_ptr<int>(temp);
foo(temp3, temp2);
```

Comment: You are saying that, before fully evaluating one parameter value, compiler may start evaluating another? Why is that so? Is it difficult to guarantee the evaluation order? or at least one will be fully evaluated before another begins?

Comment: It simply because standard did specify the order of evaluation

Comment: If the compiler's instruction scheduler sees holes in the pipeline of a basic block, it'll shuffle things around to fill them without regard for expression boundaries, only data dependence.  If you've got dependencies on function-argument order of evaluation, you've just wrecked maintainability: the one question maintainers must ask is "is this change safe?", and hoisting argument calculations out of an argument list is often a good thing to do.  If C++ permits dependencies here the answer changes from "yes" to "good luck".  That being the case, there's no reason to hobble the optimizer.